# How to laod html data in to div tag along with javascript in windows8 metro apps

Tags: javascript, html

Hi i have a small issue here i need to load another html data along with javascript in to another div with out using iframes. Actually i tried iframes but some other issues like back is not possible and data is refresh in that so i like to try with div tag to call html along with javascript file. can any one tell me how to solve this, thanks in advance.